# + near elements value postgresql

Tags: postgresql

While I was trying to solve an issue (asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048123/data-is-not-part-of-enum-values)), I just bump on that type of result when I want to see which data are stored inside an Enum :

```
 Schema |    Name     | Internal name | Size |    Elements    | Owner | Access privileges | Description 
--------+-------------+---------------+------+----------------+-------+-------------------+-------------
 public | rights_enum | rights_enum   | 4    | Administrateur+| cvt   |                   | 
        |             |               |      | Utilisateur    |       |                   |
```

where `rights_enum` is my enumeration type. As you can see, I've got 2 values inside this Enum :

- `Administrateur`
- `Utilisateur`

What is the meaning of `+` next to Element values (next to `Administrateur`)? I don't think that it's just something for display.

Edit : Here is my user table (almost empty due to development) :

```
 id |        email        |     phone      |                           hashpass                           |  nom   | prenom |   rights    
----+---------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-------------
  1 | micheljean@test.com | 06 54 32 12 34 | $2y$10$5HMULhzKrWSEfCeGklyCueVVwySPFKMqrxw/EqF7V0q3FM99Ejvnu | michel | jean   | Utilisateur
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the meaning of + next to Element values (next to
>   Administrateur)? I don't think that it's just something for display.

Short answer: Yes it is. `+` at the right of the field represents a newline.

Long answer: The result shown comes from `\dT+` in psql with the enum type as parameter.

For instance:

```
=> create type mytype as enum('one','two','three');
=> \dT+ mytype
                                      List of data types
 Schema |  Name  | Internal name | Size | Elements | Owner  | Access privileges | Description 
--------+--------+---------------+------+----------+--------+-------------------+-------------
 public | mytype | mytype        | 4    | one     +| daniel |                   | 
        |        |               |      | two     +|        |                   | 
        |        |               |      | three    |        |                   |
```

This command sends a query that you can see with the setting: `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`

```
=> \set ECHO_HIDDEN on
=> \dT+ mytype
********* QUERY **********
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) AS "Name",
  t.typname AS "Internal name",
  CASE WHEN t.typrelid != 0
      THEN CAST('tuple' AS pg_catalog.text)
    WHEN t.typlen < 0
      THEN CAST('var' AS pg_catalog.text)
    ELSE CAST(t.typlen AS pg_catalog.text)
  END AS "Size",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(
      ARRAY(
          SELECT e.enumlabel
          FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum e
          WHERE e.enumtypid = t.oid
          ORDER BY e.enumsortorder
      ),
      E'\n'
  ) AS "Elements",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(t.typowner) AS "Owner",
pg_catalog.array_to_string(t.typacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
    pg_catalog.obj_description(t.oid, 'pg_type') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_type t
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
WHERE (t.typrelid = 0 OR (SELECT c.relkind = 'c' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c WHERE c.oid = t.typrelid))
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_type el WHERE el.oid = t.typelem AND el.typarray = t.oid)
  AND (t.typname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(mytype)$'
        OR pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid, NULL) OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(mytype)$')
  AND pg_catalog.pg_type_is_visible(t.oid)
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Then you can find the origin of these newlines: they come from `pg_catalog.array_to_string()` with the enum labels passed as an array and `E'\n'` as the separator, a.k.a linefeed.

Answer (score 1):

The Administrator in the table is marked by a `+` to indicate that the person who is currently accessing the database is an administrator of the database, not an non-admin user.

Comment: I used the owner account to access to these data, which isn't a user/admin registered (just references as the owner), but you're not totally false, it could refered to users that had rights to consult database

Comment: I added the user table